# seleccionar opcion c++

Tags: c++

como puedo hacer que el usuario pueda seleccionar una opcion?

-----Menu------

leer

abrir

cerrar

tengo esto, pero no funciona:

```
char menu;

cin>>menu;

while(menu != 'l' && menu != 'a' && menu != 'c'){
    cin>>opcion;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas con un do-while ya que necesitas que se ejecute al menos una vez:

```
char op;
do{
   cout << "MENU" << endl;
   cout << "1.- Leer" << endl;
   cout << "2.- Abrir" << endl;
   cout << "3.- Cerrar" << endl;
   cout << "Su opcion: ";
   cin >> op;
   switch(op){
   case '1': // LO QUE QUIERES QUE PASE
   break;
   case '2': // LO QUE QUIERES QUE PASE
   break;
   case '3': cout << "Saliendo del programa...";
   break;
   default: cout << "Opción invalida";
   break;
 }
}while(op!='3');
```

Para evitar errores coloco la variable que el usuario ingresa una opción como char para que si el usuario ingresa una letra no quede ese bucle infinito. También puedes cambiar los números por letras si quieres que se ejecute al ingresar una letra.

Comment: ok, pero la idea del ejercicio es hacer un while o do while, en el que para salir del bucle tienes que indicar una de las letras (l, a, c), (l leera un dato mas y saldra del bucle, a mostrara por pantalla un dato y cerrara el bucle, y cerrar solo saldra del bucle), pero mi problema es que cuando se introduce l, a, c no sale del bucle.

Comment: En tu código, al ingresar cualquier letra (incluso distintas a las que tú quieres que el usuario ingrese) entrará al bucle. Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa 'c', tienes la condición "menu != 'c' ", vale, no debería entrar, pero tienes un "menu != 'a' " con un "o lógico", por lo que sí entrara, porque con el "o lógico" se necesita que se cumpla al menos una para entrar. Si explicas un poco mejor te puedo seguir ayudando, solo dame más detalles exactos de lo que quieres que ocurra.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general los menús de este tipo están dentro de un while que se rompe cuando el usuario ingresa la opción de cerrar. suponiendo que lo que deseas en este tipo de menus tal vez esto te sirva

```
int opt;

while(true)
{
    std::cout << " ----- Menu --------\n" <<
              " 1- leer \n 2-escribir \n 3-cerrar\n";
    std::cin >> opt;

    if(opt == 1)
        std::cout << "leer seleccionado \n";
    else if(opt == 2)
        std::cout << "escibir seleccionado\n";
    else if(opt == 3)
        break; // aqui rompe el lazo
    else
        std::cout << "opcion invalida\n";
}
```